# Hide footer on page one if 2nd page is created

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I want to make an template in word 2010, where the footer on the first page should disappear, if I have enough text to reach the 2nd page.

The footer on the 2nd page should be different from the footer on first page. Does anyone has any suggestions, on how to achieve it? or is it not possible?

I tried this to only show the table if the number of pages equals 1, but it does not work as I thought it would. What have I done wrong?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an IF field to your First Page Footer, to test the number of pages in your document.  If number of pages is >1 then footer text on page 1 should be nothing otherwise it will insert footer text on page 1.  The footer for page 2 onwards would be set up in the Footer for the balance of your section(s).

In the screenshot below is an example of an IF field.  If number of pages is more than one, nothing is shown (denoted by the "" for the true result).  Otherwise, insert the text shown inside the second set of quotes (the false result) (which you would customise with your footer text).

[image: IF field in first page footer to show/hide text]

Comment: is it normal text form field? and is it possible to have a table in there? and if so, how can i add it to a footer? if this only works in 2016 i will have you as accepted answer. i sadly was mistaken with the version of my word

Comment: It is an IF field - I still use old shortcut key ALT i f to display the dialog.  Otherwise, you can access fields dialog via Quickparts.  Or even just press CTRL F9 to insert blank curly braces and insert what you need (you could do CTRL F9 again to insert braces for NUMPAGES field or go via the insert field dialog again).  Yes, you can insert table inside the field, just put cursor where I have "INSERT PAGE ... text and insert table in usual way there (remember to leave the closing quotation mark after the table to denote end of text to be inserted).

Comment: I updated my question with an picture of my IF field. Can you have a look at what i did wrong there? The IF field should only be visible if number of pages equals 1

Comment: The {NUMPAGES} in your screenshot doesn't look like field braces, see how they don't have the dotted outline that the main { } around your IF field do - did you just type those manually?  You just need to either use CTRL F9 to insert the blank { } and then type NUMPAGES inside those, or insert the NUMPAGES field via Insert ribbon.  Also if you want the table to appear on page 1, then you need to insert the table inside the first set of "", and then the second set would be blank "" (for other pages).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see that the NUMPAGES would need the CTRL+F9 braces as well. Now its working fine